# Error sockets c++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, socket

Tengo un problema con sockets en c++, he intentado conectar dos computadoras en la misma red, pero nada sucede realmente. Básicamente se detiene a la hora de intentar realizar la conexión entre el cliente y el servidor. He intentado con distintos códigos que he encontrado en internet, pero nada me funciona. No sé si el problema es del computador o del código. Alguno tiene alguna idea de lo que esto puede ser? Por si acaso, todo está hecho en máquinas virtuales.
Este es el código:

Código de Servidor:

```
#include "socketserver.h"

socketServer::socketServer(){}


bool socketServer::crear_Socket()
{
    descriptor = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(descriptor < 0)
        return false;
    info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    info.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    info.sin_port = htons(4050);
    memset(&info.sin_zero,0,sizeof(info.sin_zero));
    return true;
}

bool socketServer::ligar_Kernel()
{
    if((bind(descriptor,(sockaddr *)&info,(socklen_t)sizeof(info))) < 0)
        return false;

    listen(descriptor,5);
    return true;
}


void socketServer::run()
{
    if(!crear_Socket())
        throw string("Error al crear el socket");
    if(!ligar_Kernel())
        throw string("Error al  ligar kernel");

    while (true) {
        cout << "Esperando nuevo cliente"<<endl;
        dataSocket data;
        socklen_t tam = sizeof(data.info);
        data.descriptor = accept(descriptor,(sockaddr*)&data.info,&tam);
        if(data.descriptor < 0)
            cout << "Error al acceptar al cliente"<<endl;
        else
        {
            clientes.push_back(data.descriptor);
            pthread_t hilo;
            pthread_create(&hilo,0,socketServer::controladorCliente,(void *)&data);
            pthread_detach(hilo);
        }
    }
    close(descriptor);
}



void * socketServer::controladorCliente(void *obj)
{
    dataSocket *data = (dataSocket*)obj;
    while (true) {
        string mensaje;
        while (1) {
            char buffer[10] = {0};
            int bytes = recv(data->descriptor,buffer,10,0);
            mensaje.append(buffer,bytes);
            if(bytes < 10)
                break;
        }
        cout << mensaje << endl;
    }

    close(data->descriptor);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void socketServer::setMensaje(const char *msn)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < clientes.size() ; i++)
        cout << "bytes enviados "<< send(clientes[i],msn,strlen(msn),0);
}
```

Main del servidor:

```
#include <socketserver.h>


socketServer *server;

void * serverRun(void *)
{
    try{
        server->run();
    }catch(string ex)
    {
        cout << ex;
    }

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
   server = new socketServer;
   pthread_t hiloServer;
   pthread_create(&hiloServer,0,serverRun,NULL);
   pthread_detach(hiloServer);

   while (1) {
       string mensaje;
       cin >> mensaje;
       server->setMensaje(mensaje.c_str());
   }

   delete server;
   return 0;
}
```

Código del cliente:

```
#include "socketcliente.h"

SocketCliente::SocketCliente()
{
}

bool SocketCliente::connectar()
{
    descriptor = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(descriptor < 0)
        return false;
    info.sin_family = AF_INET;
    info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.16.130");
    info.sin_port = ntohs(4050);
    memset(&info.sin_zero,0,sizeof(info.sin_zero));
    if((::connect(descriptor,(sockaddr*)&info,(socklen_t)sizeof(info))) < 0)
     return false;
    pthread_t hilo;
    pthread_create(&hilo,0,SocketCliente::controlador,(void *)this);
    pthread_detach(hilo);
    return true;
}


void * SocketCliente::controlador(void *obj)
{
    SocketCliente padre = (SocketCliente)obj;

    while (true) {
        string mensaje;
        while (1) {
            char buffer[10] = {0};
            int bytes = recv(padre->descriptor,buffer,10,0);
            mensaje.append(buffer,bytes);
            if(bytes <= 0)
            {
                close(padre->descriptor);
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
            if(bytes < 10)
                break;
        }
        emit padre->NewMensaje(QString::fromStdString(mensaje));
    }
    close(padre->descriptor);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void SocketCliente::setMensaje(const char *msn)
{
   // char mensaje = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36\r\nX-Client-Data: CIm2yQEIorbJAQiptskBCLiIygEI3pbKAQ==\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nAccept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\n\n";

    cout << "bytes enviados "<< send(descriptor,msn,strlen(msn),0) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Antes de nada: ¿ puedes hacer `ping` desde una máquina virtual a la otra ? ¿ Y viceversa ?

Comment: No, no podemos hacer ping.

Comment: Pues dificílmente vas a conectar una con la otra :-) Toca buscarte algún tutorial en Internet para configurar la red de la Máquina Virtual que estés usando. Hasta que no funcione el `ping`, no hay nada mas que hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo intentaré. Si tiene alguna otra recomendación, es bienvenida. :)

Comment: Para tus primeras pruebas, puedes hacerlo todo en la misma máquina virtual, tanto el servidor como el cliente. Te ahorrarás algún que otro dolor de cabeza. Si todo funciona en una sola, pero falla al usar varias MV ... problema de configuración de red :-)